# close activity and dialog box on back press

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have an activity which has a progressdialog box with `setCancelable(false)`.

I want to finish the activity as well as dismiss the `progressdialog box` on `backPressed()`.

I have implemented `onBackPressed()` as below but it is not working.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(pDialog.isShowing()){
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
    this.finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

progress Dialog code is

```
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("Connecting to Server");
        pDialog.setMessage("Updating Assignee Detail. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
```

Comment: why can't you make pDialog.setCanceleable(true) in onBackPressed method. And `finish` and `onBackPressed` does the same thing. Delete this.finish();

Comment: What happens if you change to setCancelable(true)? Does your code work then?

Comment: post your progressdialog code.

Comment: @user57445: See my answer.It is tested successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set

```
pDialog.setCancelable(true);
```

And rest of your code is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Just dismiss the dialog in `OnStop()` rest `Activity` will `finish()` automatically by pressing back

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    if(progressDialog.isShowing()) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it in 2 following steps,

**Step-1**
Change

`pDialog.setCancelable(false)`  to

`pDialog.setCancelable(true)`

because a `Dialog` can't be cancelled if it is set to false.

**Step-2**

Add a listener to your `Dialog` so that it will listen when cancelled like following,

```
pDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                // if from activity
                finish();

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this method and no need to call the finish for the activity:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if(null != pDialog)
pDialog.dismiss();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

intead finish activity on dialog dismiss:

```
pDialog .setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little example of progress dialog, close it and activity...

**Option 1**

Create progress dialog

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this); //create progress dialog
    dialog.setMessage("¡wait it, please...!"); //body text...
    dialog.setCancelable(true); //if it will be cancelable
    //this is the listener cancelable
    dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    dialog.show(); //show it...
```

finish it in some threat or wherever you want...

```
 dialog.dismiss();
```

on backpressed

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(dialog.isShowing()){
        dialog.cancel();
    }
    finish();
}
```

**Option 2**

Create a global var

```
Boolean validation=false;
```

Create progress dialog

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this); //create progress dialog
    dialog.setMessage("¡wait it, please...!"); //body text...
    dialog.setCancelable(false); //if it will be cancelable
    //this is the listener dismiss
    dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                if(validation){
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }else{
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
    dialog.show(); //show it...
```

finish it

```
 //if finish process 
 validation=true;
 dialog.dismiss();
```

or

```
 //if finish with backpress
 validation=false;
 dialog.dismiss();
```

on backpressed

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(dialog.isShowing()){
        validation=false;
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    finish();
}
```